# pip install matplotlib on termux failed

Tags: matplotlib, pip, termux

I am trying to install matplolib on android device using termux, but have been failing.

I have installed libjpeg-turbo and zlib, and tried installing other packages libtiff, libwebp, openjpeg, and so on.

But it is still failing.(Error message has been changed though)

anyone solved this problem?

Part of the error message below.

(the entire message is to long)

```
building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
    aarch64-linux-android-clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/freetype2 -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/openjpeg-2.4 -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/fribidi -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10/src/_imagingmorph.o                                           aarch64-linux-android-clang -shared -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -landroid-support -L/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r23b-api-24-v4/sysroot/usr/lib -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -fopenmp -static-openmp -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -landroid-support -L/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r23b-api-24-v4/sysroot/usr/lib build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10/src/_imagingmorph.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -L/system/lib -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -lpython3.10 -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.10/PIL/_imagingmorph.cpython-310.so
    ld.lld: error: /system/lib/libdl.so is incompatible with aarch64linux                                        ld.lld: error: /system/lib/libc.so is incompatible with aarch64linux
    ld.lld: error: /system/lib/libdl.so is incompatible with aarch64linux                                        clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang' failed with exit code 1     ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-ph9ufjl1/pillow_dc19fcb286984db9872b8b4c61d3d8d9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-ph9ufjl1/pillow_dc19fcb286984db9872b8b4c61d3d8d9/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-z4n90t_6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.10/pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2):

Termux's package manager contains the `matplotlib` package.

So you can install `matplotlib` via

```
pkg install matplotlib
```

and after that `matplotlib` can be imported in the Python version (`3.10.4` as of 2022/04/09) even one fails to configure `pip` to install `matplotlib`.

(You can see the actual dependencies by `pkg show matplotlib`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help, but I personaly could not install Pillow and some other libraries on my termux without this (flags?):

```
LDFLAGS="-L/system/lib64/" CFLAGS="-I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/" pip install matplotlib
```

It's probably an error that has to do with our phones using the "AArch64" ARM architecture.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it did not work though :( the flag thing did work for pillow.